# Sorting (or usage of ORDER BY clause) in T-SQL / SQL SERVER without considering some words

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i'm wondering whether it is possible to use ORDER BY clause (or any other clause(s)) to do sorting without considering some words.

For ex, article 'the':

1. Bank of Switzerland
2. Bank of America
3. The Bank of England

should be sorted into:

1. Bank of America
2. The Bank of England
3. Bank of Switzerland

and NOT

1. Bank of America
2. Bank of Switzerland
3. The Bank of England

Comment: Its more complex, but you could implement a fulltext search on your table, create a stop list and add the words you dont want to it

Comment: If the rule is any more complex than "ignore a leading 'the' when sorting" you may want to consider having separate columns for `DisplayName` and `SortName`.

Comment: Sorry that is not possible because I don't have the authority to modify the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from #test
order by
case when test like 'The %' then substring(test, 5, 8000) else test end
```

Comment: I've decided to go with this solution because it is the simplest solution that I can implement on my situation. using 'replace' like other solution posted here is not very readable (for more than one word) although I tested it and it is also working perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limited number of words that you wish to eliminate, then you might be able to remove them by judicious use of `REPLACE`, e.g.

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(' ' + Column + ' ',' the ',' '),' and ',' ')
```

However, as the number of words add up, you'll have more and more nested `REPLACE` calls. In addition, this `ORDER BY` will be unable to benefit from any indexes, and doesn't cope with punctuation marks.

If this sort is frequent and the queries would otherwise be able to benefit from an index, you might consider making the above a computed column, and creating an index over it (You would then order by the computed column).

Answer (score 2):

No, not really because `the` is arbitrary in this case. The closest you can do is modify the field value, such as below:

```
SELECT   field1
FROM     table
ORDER BY REPLACE(field1, 'The ', '')
```

The problem is that to replace two words, you have to next `REPLACE` statements, which becomes a huge issue if you have more than about five words:

```
SELECT   field1
FROM     table
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(field1, 'of ', ''), 'The ', '')
```

**Update:** You don't really need to check if `the` or `of` appears at the beginning of the field because you are only wanting to sort by important words anyway. For example, `Bank of America` should appear before `Bank England` (the `of` shouldn't make it selected *after*).

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode a method of turning one string into another and then ordering by that.

For example, if the method is just to strip away starting occurances of 'The '...

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN LEFT(yourField, 4) = 'The ' THEN RIGHT(yourField, LEN(yourField)-4) ELSE yourField END
```

Or, if you want to ignore all occurrences of 'the', where ever it occurs, just use REPLACE...

```
ORDER BY
  REPLACE(yourField, 'The', '')
```

You may end up with a fairly complex transposition, in which case you can do things like this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    <complex transposition> AS new_name,
    *
  FROM
    whatever
)
  AS data
ORDER BY
  new_name
```

Comment: `REPLACE(yourField, 'The', '')` is dangerous, since it will replace any occurrence of those 3 characters, including those inside other words (and leave a space character where one should probably not exist, in order for the next word to compare correctly against a string that hasn't had "the" removed)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : That's exactly correct, but I leave that up to the OP to work out when considering punctuation (before and after the searched for characters), etc.  And it's also why I'd use the `LEFT()` based check for the OP's *exact* question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, replacing any 'the' by replace(yourField, 'The', '') is also my concern and using LEFT() is surely better. However I decided to use the case..when and substring method, but your solution also works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution a little bit shorter

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Name varchar(100) );

INSERT INTO @Temp (Name)
SELECT 'Bank of Switzerland'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bank of America'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'The Bank of England'

SELECT * FROM @Temp
ORDER BY LTRIM(REPLACE(Name, 'The ', ''))
```